# Mimicking java packages in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

So this is a very newbie question, but, I am messing around with C# and just recently finished a very large Java project for my Software engineering class. In that project we had to rely quite heavily on different packages that each contained specific roles.

I was wondering how to go about creating packages for my C# code in VS? Namely, in Eclipse I just make a new package, say something like package.mypackage.myItem. I want to know how to make something similar to that in VS so that instead of just saying `using myClass`, it would something like using `MyCustoms.myClass`.

Apologies if this question was asked before, could not find it. Also apologies if this is not the correct place to ask it.

Comment: Nvm, figured it out, similar process just folder creation is a bit unusual to how I am used to.

Comment: Google Namespaces. You do not need to create folders.